# backpropagation manually not equal with weights keras

Tags: python, keras, pytorch, neural-network, backpropagation

I calculated the backpropagation manually and also obtained the weights with the keras, but it is not equal.
[calculated the backpropagation manually picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pqhP.png)
I calculated the backpropagation manually is 0.19926 and output keras weights is 0.19882499

[this is my mlp picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQSZZ.png)

```
from keras.mixed_precision.loss_scale_optimizer import optimizer 
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

xtrain=[[0,0]]
ytrain=[[0]]
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(2,))
x=keras.layers.Dense(5,activation="sigmoid", use_bias=False, bias_initializer='zeros')(inputs)
output=layers.Dense(1,activation="sigmoid", use_bias=False, bias_initializer='zeros')(x)
model=keras.Model(inputs=inputs,outputs=output,name="xor")
model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error',
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(
    learning_rate=0.01,
    momentum=0.0,
    nesterov=False,
    weight_decay=0.0,
    clipnorm=None,
    clipvalue=None,
    global_clipnorm=None,
    use_ema=False,
    ema_momentum= 0,
    ema_overwrite_frequency=None,
    jit_compile=True,
    name="SGD",

))
i=0
for layerNum, layer in enumerate(model.layers):
    if(i==1):
      layer.set_weights([np.array([[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1],[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1]])])
    if(i==2):
      layer.set_weights([np.array([[0.2],[0.2],[0.2],[0.2],[0.2]])])
    i=i+1

history=model.fit(xtrain,ytrain,batch_size=1,epochs=1)

for layerNum, layer in enumerate(model.layers):

    weights = layer.get_weights()
    print("weights=",weights)
    print(layerNum,"layerNum")
```

Comment: You do the manual computation with about 3 digits, so it is not astonishing if the result is only correct in the leading 3 digits (after rounding). Repeat the manual computation with a higher number of digits and compare if the result improves accordingly.